# Input data amount for Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I want to use Caffe and the googlenet structure coming with Caffe to train a model based on my own image data. 
I have 14 categories for classification. But I do have only around 250 images for training and 80 for testing. Is this enough? Are there means to find out how many images I need per class?

Comment: this is very little amount of data. can you obtain more?

Comment: Yes, I can. Is there a way to find out, what's a good number?

Comment: a million would be nice, but I believe you can do with less ;)

Comment: Oh, okay, I have to take the images manually :/ Can I somehow figure out what's a good number in advance?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, the top layer of GoogLeNet has dimension of 1024. this means you have to fine tune over 1000 free variables per class.

Comment: You may want to fine-tune the last layers of a pre-trained network if you have so few data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:
Just finetune the top layer since you only have such few data. By this way, you can think the network as a feature extractor and you just train a classifier on top this features.

Solution 2:
Try aggressive data augmentation. For example you can try random translation, scaling, rotation of your data. In this way, you can get a lot of images from one training image.

Solution 3:
The most effective way is to try to get more real data. Data is very important for deep learning. As a rule of thumb, at least 1000 images for one class.

Comment: With Solution 1 I get good results, almost 0.9 accuracy on the google inception net.